# itext android digital signature verification

Tags: android, itext, digital-signature, verification

i am able to digitally sign pdf , during *signature verification in android* getting error as

> **Supplied key (null) is not a RSAPublicKey instance**

but the same code in simple java for same PDF file it is verifying, integrity check is giving true. what is the issue with android itext version?

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please.

Comment: first created private key & CSR using OPENSSL then got trial cert from thawte , using the leaf cert & private key to sign PDf. During verification process the above error i am getting.

Comment: mkl means a code sample, a signed pdf, etc.